# Python - calling a function

Tags: python

This is a Python function to return the cost of a trip. I can't figure out what's wrong with this - nothing gets called. Am I missing something?

```
    def hotel_cost(nights):
        return 140 * nights

    def plane_ride_cost(city):
        if city == "Charlotte":
            return 183
        elif city == "Tampa":
            return 220
        elif city == "Pittsburgh":
            return 222
        elif city == "Los Angeles":
            return 475

    def rental_car_cost(days):
        total_car = days * 40
        if days >= 7:
           total_car -= 50
        elif days >= 3:
            total_car -= 20
        return total_car

    def trip_cost(city, days):
        return rental_car_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + hotel_cost(days)

print trip_cost("Charlotte", 6)
```

Comment: You have an indentation problem; your last line should not be indented at all.

Comment: That doesn't fix it..

Comment: You might have forgotten to print your result. Try `print(trip_cost())`

Comment: Without the indentation before `trip_cost("Charlotte", 6)` the code works fine. How are you running it ?

Comment: through idle - it just doesn't give a result

Comment: the function is getting called, you need to print the result.

Answer (score 0):

write

```
print trip_cost("Charlotte", 6)
```

you are calling the function 'trip_cost' and getting the return value, but you are not doing anything with the return value. To see the output use print

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me and returns 1243 :

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    total_car = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
       total_car -= 50
    elif days >= 3:
        total_car -= 20
    return total_car

def trip_cost(city, days):
    return rental_car_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + hotel_cost(days)

print(trip_cost("Charlotte", 6))
```

I just removed some useless indentation and added a "print"